# Application of integrating $\cos^4 x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, applications, motivation

A student asked a colleague the other day for a *practical application* that involved needing to integrate the fourth power of cosine, but no one here could think of one off-hand other than some volume of revolution problem where the radius involved the second power of cosine.

Anyone have any examples from physics or engineering that the context of the application would be accessible to a Calculus II student?

Comment: The question is misplaced. The student is probably trying to show by an example that what he's learning doesn't have applications by catching the professor out on this particular example. He may get an answer here and be able to say why it's important to be able to integrate $\cos^4 x$, but if the student had asked about $23 \cos^4 x$, he'd be stuck. That may sound dumb, but it's really just taking the logic of asking about $\cos^4 x$ a step further. The appropriate question is whether the methods being learned to attack a broad class of problems, of which $\cos^4 x$ is just one example,...

Comment: have practical applications. Your colleague shouldn't hesitate to answer the broader question and say, "Once you've learned these methods, integrating $\cos^4 x$ is just one easy example of what you can do."

Comment: Some such questions are very appropriate at [matheducators.se].

Comment: Thanks to Care Bear for pointing me to the Math Ed Stack Exchange.  I arrived here today because someone on the AP Calc list serve pointed to a particular question and answer here.